# How to stop a PostgreSQL query automatically when the table is locked?

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql

I have a bash script that creates new partitions for the tables in the database. I'm currently having a problem with locked tables - when this script runs and tries to create partitions for a table that is being used otherwise, it gets stuck. All I need is to find a way to stop the script after a certain amount of time when the table is locked, but so far I haven't succeeded.

This is the code block where the problem occurs:

```
>&3 2>&4 psql -h $host -d $database -U $database_user -t -e -c "ALTER TABLE ${schema}.${table} SPLIT DEFAULT PARTITION START (date '${partition_date_to_create}') INCLUSIVE END (date '${exclusive_date}') EXCLUSIVE INTO (PARTITION \""${partition_name}"\", PARTITION ${default_partition_name})"
```

It's part of this block:

```
  do
    partition_name="${partition_date_to_create//-/}"
    if [ -n "${existent_partition[*]}" ] && [[ "${existent_partition[*]}" == *"$partition_name"* ]]; then
        log_info "Table ${table} already has partition '${partition_name}'. Skipping creation."
        continue
    fi

    log_info "Creating partition '${partition_name}' for table ${table}..."
    exclusive_date=$(date --date="${partition_date_to_create} +1 day" +%F)
    >&3 2>&4 psql -h $host -d $database -U $database_user -t -e -c "ALTER TABLE ${schema}.${table} SPLIT DEFAULT PARTITION START (date '${partition_date_to_create}') INCLUSIVE END (date '${exclusive_date}') EXCLUSIVE INTO (PARTITION \""${partition_name}"\", PARTITION ${default_partition_name})"

    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
      log_info "Created partition '${partition_name}' for table ${table}."
    else
      log_error "Error creating partition '${partition_name}' for table ${table}."
    fi
  done
```

What I have tried so far:

- Set the variable ON_ERROR_STOP to ON;
- Configure LOCK_TIMEOUT;
- Configure STATEMENT_TIMEOUT;
- Disable the autocommit feature and commit manually.

Can anyone offer me an insight on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: `lock_timeout` is pointless if it is set to the same or a larger value than `statement_timeout` since the statement timeout will always trigger first.

Comment: I would try to wrap the DDL statement with a transaction: `BEGIN;` … `COMMIT;`

Comment: How did you configure the lock timeout?

Comment: You could try `lock table ... in exclusive mode nowait` before doing the ALTER TABLE. But that should run in the same transaction as the following ALTER TABLE.

Comment: @wp78de I configured `lock_timeout` and `statement_timeout` each one at a time, none of them worked.

Comment: @wp78de The autocommit feature is active, I tried disabling it and using `BEGIN; ... COMMIT;` but also it did't work.

Comment: @Jeremy this is what I did:  `>&3 2>&4 psql -h $host -d $database -U $database_user -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -t -e  -c "SET lock_timeout = 20000"  -c " ALTER TABLE...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider executing the psql for 'alter table' under Linux 'timeout`. It will force command to abort and will terminate the postgres connection/pending command (similar to Ctrl/C).

```
timeout 60s psql -h $host -d $database -U $database_user -t -e -c "ALTER TABLE ..."
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution used `timeout` is great and simple. However it could be more accurate:

```
#!/bin/bash
psql -c "<your statement here>" & # start job in background
pid=$! # get PID of it
sleep 2 # wait for a time (2 sec here)
locktype=$(psql -AXt -c "select wait_event_type from pg_stat_activity where pid = $pid") # get the lock type for te PID
if [[ ${locktype,,} =~ '*lock*' ]] ; then # if session is still locked then kill it
    psql -c "select pg_cancel_backend($pid)"
fi
```

PS: Instead of `'*lock*'` you should to provide your specific wait type.

Comment: Revised; The `pid` on pg_stat_activity refer to the backend (server) PID. To locate a server by client try using 'client_hostname' and 'client_port' to select the correct connection.